# AS3 - KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN in AIR project not triggering handler after removing display objects, and stage.focus not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, desktop-application, keyboard-events

I am developing an kiosk-like application (a game) which needs to be locked in full screen all the time. I am using as3/flash/AIR for it. Things started well at first, and for the most part all works fine.. but there is a mystery brewing somewhere which I haven't been able to figure out... That's where your help would be greatly appreciated!

The way I handled this problem is by adding at the very beginning of the app:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, playerOnKeyDown);
```

Then, on my playerOnKeyDown function:

```
function playerOnKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        //More code here opening out menus, etc, etc.)
    }
}
```

So, all of this worked just fine, but of course I needed to also bring along:

```
stage.focus = stage;
```

into the party, otherwise, when removing objects - as in removeChild() - the event firing wouldn't behave as I wanted, because flash changed the focus elsewhere in the display list.

I have been careful to add the focus to the stage every time a remove a "child", and it works great everywhere, except for one time in the entire run, right after I remove an object from an externally loaded swf.

I still add the lines as it should be expected to work:

```
removeChild(childFromLoadedSWF);
stage.focus = stage;
```

except that when I hit the any key, the event won't trigger my function, and if I hit the ESC key, it takes me out of full screen (its default behavior), once again, circumventing completely my listener function playerOnKeyDown.

The strange thing is that right before doing this, the line:

```
stage.hasEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN))
```

traces true!

The focus is on the stage, the listener is on, and yet when pressing the ESC key the default behavior is ignoring my function completely....

What could be causing this?

THANK YOU!!

Comment: Well, looks like at least on applications packaged for AIR it does work. As a matter of fact the code above works great almost all the time, by preventing the default behavior of the ESC key. The problem is not that, but the fact that it will circumvent my listener. Not just the ESC key, but ANY key.... Something else must be going on...

Comment: It's as if the listener had been removed, except is not . It is completely bypassing my listener function playerOnKeyDown.

Comment: Can you help me with my problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68391014/adobe-animate-keyboard-event-wont-run-before-click-the-stage Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to remove an ENTER_FRAME listener I had. That was wreaking havoc with the stage.focus. Now everything works great!

```
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame)
```

For anyone looking into using AS3 to develop desktop games for mac or PC (as in Steam), this is great.

the game Machinarium must have done something like this, because the ESC key never causes this effect, event though it was made in flash.